# MagicalRecord release/3.0 - Logging not working

Tags: magicalrecord

I use the latest build available for "release/3.0" branch.

Installing using CocoaPods

```
pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => 'https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git', :branch => 'release/3.0'
```

Setup my stack as:

```m
#define MR_LOGGING_ENABLED 1
#import <MagicalRecord.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [MagicalRecord setupiCloudStackWithLocalStoreNamed:@"MyStoreName"];
    [[MagicalRecordStack defaultStack] setLoggingEnabled:YES];
}
```

than i make some Core Data saving

```m
[[MagicalRecordStack defaultStack] saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    Canvas *canvas = [Canvas MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
    canvas.title = text;
    canvas.type = CanvasTypeAdditional;
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        @strongify(self);
        self.data = [Canvas MR_findAll];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}];
```

No log is printed into Xcode console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a page on our wiki about this: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/wiki/Logging, but essentially there are two parts to enabling logging:

1. You need to add `#define MR_LOGGING_ENABLED 1` (which you have done);
2. If you're using CocoaPods, you need to use the logging variant of the podspec: `pod 'MagicalRecord/Core+Logging', :git => 'https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git', :branch => 'release/3.0'`

Once you've updated your Podfile to use the logging sub spec, run `pod update` and you should see log output!

We wanted to give people the flexibility to disable/enable logging in production builds without needing to mess with their CocoaPods Xcode project.

Comment: I think this should be documented here: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/develop/Docs/Logging.md